# Office 365 installation failed on Windows 10 - Now I cannot install/update anything

Tags: windows, windows-10, office365

I attempted to update Office 365 on Windows 10, but it hung during installation. Now if I try and install it again I get an error about an existing installation being in progress.

Now I cannot install or update anything.

I assume I need to monkey around in the registry, but I don't want to do this without some guidance.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't use tools to fix your registry.  If you want help with your problem we need some specifics.  If you attempt to fix your registry you will make the problem worst, and at that point, we won't be able to help.

Comment: At what percentage of the installation did it hang? There are various solutions on the Microsoft websites that apply depending on whether it's 79%, 80%-95% or otherwise.

Comment: I'm getting the same kind of problems (Windows 10 too), but somewhat worse: the installation program completes after a long time, but there are no shortcuts, nothing called EXCEL.EXE anywhere on the hard drives for example. I'm sick and tired with this Office. it's getting worse and worse. Sad to say, but I wish everyone switched to openoffice or libreoffice, and maybe MS would make things work easy again (at least as it used to be several years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by doing the following:-

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete, and then click Task Manager.
2. Right-click OfficeclickTorun.exe and then click End Task. I did this for each instance.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has [a "Fixit" program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en?wa=wsignin1.0) that should automatically clean up programs that can't be installed or uninstalled.

If that doesn't work, there's [a free utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.utilityspotlight.aspx) on a Microsoft TechNet blog that seems to do something similar, but targeted at individual programs.

Comment: FixIt doesn't support Windows 10 yet.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried re-starting your computer? Windows works better after a restart -

Also if you want to clean out registry I use this tool here that allows you to backup any change and then run an automated scan / clean  -

https://www.ccleaner.com/

-IT Specialist for a few years.